# Converting a 2d cell array to 3d array

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have a 2d (20 x 1) cell array and each cell is a 601 x 4 matrix. I want to convert it into 601 x 4 x 20 matrix. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate along the third dimension:

```
cat(3, x{:}); % where `x` is the cell array.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the cell array is c,

```
new_matrix =[]
for i=1:size(c,1)
new_matrix(:,:,i) = c {i,1}
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I',m happy to see a new user answering MATLAB questions! There are a few things I would change here though: `new_matrix = []` is bad practice since you create a matrix that grows inside a loop. `new_matrix = zeros([size(x{1}),numel(x)])` is better. `size(c,1)` is actually the same as `numel(c)` which is a lot faster and it's harder to make mistakes ("was it the first or second dimension..?"). `i` and `j` are frowned upon as variable names, since they denote the imaginary unit (`sqrt(-1)`). This isn't a big issue if you're not working with complex numbers, but nevertheless.